# ggplot2 removes zero when using scale_x_sqrt

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I plot data whose x coordinate starts with zero using `ggplot2` and I use the `scale_x_sqrt` option, the plot starts from 1 on the x-axis instead of zero. If I add `limits=c(-0.1, 100)` I get an error that "NaNs produced". How can I get ggplot2 to include zero?

Answer (score 6):

You can have the axis go down to zero with a square root transformation, but not below zero. The transformation produces imaginary values for x-values below zero.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_sqrt(limits=c(0,6), breaks=0:6, expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

See: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/980

The workaround they describe is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
mysqrt_trans <- function() {
    trans_new("mysqrt", 
              transform = base::sqrt,
              inverse = function(x) ifelse(x<0, 0, x^2),
              domain = c(0, Inf))
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(trans="mysqrt", limits=c(0, NA))
```

In contrast to the other answers poster here this allows for some space to the left of zero.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `expand_limits` in ggplot2 like below:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
g <- g + expand_limits(x = 0, y = 0 )
g
```

[image]

```
?geom_expand
```

**Description**

> Sometimes you may want to ensure limits include a single value, for
>   all panels or all plots. This function is a thin wrapper around
>   geom_blank that makes it easy to add such values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqrt` inside `aes`:

```
# Generate data
foo <- data.frame(a = 0:10, b = 1:11)
# Plot data
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(foo, aes(sqrt(a), b)) + 
    geom_point()
```

[image]